# PhpHtmlPraser html find function won't work

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the data out of html site.
But i now that the line `<span data-bind="data-title">Absolut Combat</span>` exists.
But my code won't find it do you guys see anything wrong?

```
public function index(Request $request) 
{
    $url = 'https://umod.org/plugins';
    $dom = new Dom;
    $html = $dom->loadFromUrl($url);
    $html = $html->find('span[data-bind="data-title"]'); <-- Problem is here
    dd($html);
    return view('server.rustplugins');
}
```

Comment: its not in the dom as its in `<script id="list-view" type="text/template">`, you can only parse whats on the dom as-is (essentially a *right-click view source*), not what's added to the dom by js

Comment: call https://umod.org/plugins/search.json?query=&page=1&sort=title&sortdir=asc&filter=&author= instead then json decode it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the json instead of writing a html grabber.